How to find resolution why QuerySimple(const RF::Primitives::CRay3& pickingRay) is returning false?
QuerySimple(const RF::Primitives::CRay3& pickingRay) method is getting false for only one scenario, but for others, it's getting true. However, how can I cross-verify that both (3D picking Ray and Triangulation) are getting the correct results? Or could you suggest how I can find the cause of this issue?
The initial guess was on the pickingRay, which is what I was passing into the method. But if the same approach works for other scenarios, then it needs to work with same scenario where QuerySimple is returning false.

Sorry, what library are you talking about? Where is your [mcve], your current and expected output? Please [edit] your question to add the missing info.

Btw. it couldn't hurt to take the [tour] and read [ask] to get used with how this site works.
